# React component to animate planets on a canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, react.js, canvas

I wrote some JavaScript to generate some graphics on a canvas, on a regular HTML page.

I now want the same code to run in a component that is part of a React app. I've done this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const canvas = this.refs.firstCanvas
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    const bgCanvas = this.refs.firstbgCanvas
    const bgCtx = bgCanvas.getContext('2d')

    function generateStarfield() {
      bgCtx.clearRect(0, 0, bgCanvas.width, bgCanvas.height)
      for (let i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        bgCtx.beginPath()
        const x = Math.random()*bgCanvas.width
        const y = Math.random()*bgCanvas.height
        bgCtx.arc(x, y, 0.35, 0, 2*Math.PI, 'anticlockwise')
        bgCtx.closePath()
        bgCtx.fillStyle = 'white'
        bgCtx.fill()
      }
    }
    generateStarfield()

    const origin_x = 1000
    const origin_y = 1000
    const scale = 1000

    class planet {
      constructor(orbital_velocity, offset_theta, orbital_radius, radius, colour) {
        this.orbital_velocity = orbital_velocity
        this.orbital_radius = orbital_radius
        this.colour = colour
        this.radius = radius
        this.offset_theta = offset_theta
        this.draw()
      }

      draw() {
      const theta = this.offset_theta + (t*this.orbital_velocity)
      const x = origin_x + (this.orbital_radius*Math.cos(theta))
      const y = origin_y + (this.orbital_radius*Math.sin(theta))
      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.arc(x, y, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, 'anticlockwise')
      ctx.closePath()
      ctx.fillStyle = this.colour
      ctx.fill()
      }
    }


    let t = 0

    const a = new planet((0.2+0.4*Math.random())*Math.PI, 2*Math.random()*Math.PI, scale*0.1, 10, 'white')
    const b = new planet((0.2+0.4*Math.random())*Math.PI, 2*Math.random()*Math.PI, scale*0.2, 16, 'white')
    const c = new planet((0.2+0.4*Math.random())*Math.PI, 2*Math.random()*Math.PI, scale*0.3, 18, 'white')
    const d = new planet((0.2+0.4*Math.random())*Math.PI, 2*Math.random()*Math.PI, scale*0.4, 14, 'white')
    const e = new planet((0.2+0.4*Math.random())*Math.PI, 2*Math.random()*Math.PI, scale*0.5, 12, 'white')
    const f = new planet((0.2+0.4*Math.random())*Math.PI, 2*Math.random()*Math.PI, scale*0.6, 28, 'white')
    const g = new planet((0.2+0.4*Math.random())*Math.PI, 2*Math.random()*Math.PI, scale*0.7, 22, 'white')
    const h = new planet((0.2+0.4*Math.random())*Math.PI, 2*Math.random()*Math.PI, scale*0.8, 20, 'white')

    setInterval(function() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
      ctx.beginPath()
      a.draw()
      b.draw()
      c.draw()
      d.draw()
      e.draw()
      f.draw()
      g.draw()
      h.draw()
      t += 0.05
    }, 40)
  }
```

Now, this works (!), but I've just lifted it directly from the original JavaScript, and modified the `document.getElementByID` calls to use `ref`s. Is it bad practice to stick all of this stuff into `componentDidMount`?

Note - I'm aware that the code itself could be tidied up, I'm mainly asking about putting all of this (especially the definitions for `planet` and `generateStarField`) into `componentDidMount`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do this, if it works... but it's not really using the React architecture or patterns.

- Most of this code that is drawing should be in the `render` method.
- You'll want to move some of the state (`canvas`, `ctx`, `bgCanvas`, `bgCtx`) into the class's state, or just as instance variables.
- You can probably do most of the creation in the constructor, although doing it in `componentDidMount` will work.
- You can integrate the animation with React, 
  `setInterval(() => this.forceUpdate(() => this.t += 0.05))`. This makes sense in componentDidMount. You'll also want to turn this off in the unmount method.

### EDIT/ADDED LATER

...maybe you just want to leave it the way it is, although it's quite non-React... it's working fine, though, and there aren't really problems...

To make it "React" you're probably going to have to re-write it completely-- because just moving pieces around like I suggested may make you end up fighting the framework more than leveraging. Looking more, you'd probably make separate components for the different canvases and perhaps pass in `t` as a property, so there's a container component that functions as the "clock". Doing something like that would allow the regular React rendering mechanisms work.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the order of this  - the canvas, ctx, bgCanvas, and bgCtx can't be defined until after render has completed (as render creates the <canvas /> elements), so how can any drawing be done until the componentDidMount?

Comment: Yeah, there's a bit of a start-up ordering issue, but I think having  `React.createRef()` in the constructor and then you can just check in the `render` if it's set will work...

Comment: No you should not render animated content via `setInterval` and worse as canvas context is completely independent of the DOM you should never animate its content via reacts `forceUpdate`. Should use `requestAnimationFrame` in `componentDidMount` and stop it in `componentWillUnmount()`